# How to prompt for a single slot value in an intent containing multiple slots in Alexa using Python

Tags: python, alexa-skills-kit

I'm using the `ask_sdk_core` in an AWS Lambda written in Python to handle the logic for an Alexa app. The intent in question is a way for a researcher to capture a weight associated with a sample number. The intent is structured like `Record [weight] grams for sample [sample_number]`. The sample number must be a 6 digit integer and the weight is a decimal number. Originally I developed a Lex skill and there you can prompt for specific slot values, so if the intent arrived with an ill-formed sample number (e.g. a five digit number) I could prompt for just the sample number but leave the weight captured as is.

The lambda function uses classes to handle intents, so my structure is below. `add_weight` extracts values from slots, passes them through a validator which returns values for `speech` and `reprompt` which informs the user if they provided ill-formed sample numbers or ill-formed weights. Right now though, the user has to redo the whole prompt.

**Is there a way to preserve the well-formed values and prompt the user for just the missing value?** Right now it seems like I would have to create an intent for each slot to handle that kind of user input but that feels bad.

```py
class AddWeightHandler(AbstractRequestHandler):
    """Handler for AddWeight Intent."""

    def can_handle(self, handler_input):
        # type: (HandlerInput) -> bool
        return ask_utils.is_intent_name("AddWeight")(handler_input)

    def handle(self, handler_input):
        # type: (HandlerInput) -> Response
        speech, reprompt = add_weight(handler_input)

        return (
            handler_input.response_builder
                         .speak(speech)
                         .ask(reprompt)
                         .response
        )
```

Answer (score 1):

You need a state machine. If I'm understanding your setup correctly…

1. an Intent like "NumberOnly" that accepts just a `AMAZON.NUMBER` slot
2. a handler for each of the different numbers you want to accept (*e.g.,* `AddSampleNumberHandler`)
3. that handler's `can_handle` needs to say something like `is_intent_name("NumberOnly") and session_attributes['state'] == 'sample_number'`
4. the intent that is requesting a "NumberOnly" response needs to set the state (`AddWeightHandler` would need to set `session_attributes['state'] = 'sample_number'`)